# Using python reduce() a little bit like javaScripts reduce() but failing doing so

Tags: python, lambda

I want to use reduce() in Python but somehow I fail at some point and I don't know why:
This is my code:

```
def test(self):
    arry = [1,2,3,4,5]
    summe = reduce(lambda x, y: self.summa(x, y), arry)
    return summe

def summa(self, x, y):
    if str(type(x)) == "<class 'int'>":
        arr = []
        arr.append(x)
        x = arr
    return x.append(y)
```

I am trying to create an Array where every position is a sum of all previous positions from arry.
The problem is that the first iteration my summa function realizes that x is an integer and I succeed to convert ist to an array, but in the second iteration x is suddenly an objecto of NoneType this is my error message:

```
    return x.append(y)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: `append` returns `None`, not a list. Also, use `isinstance(x, int)` rather than your string comparison. Finally, what is `summa` supposed to do? Add two numbers, or build up a new list? What is the expected result of `test`?

Comment: Ok it might be that my understanding of reduce() is not right. Test should give me an Array that would look like this: [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]. Would it be possible to rewrite this with map somehow? The Idea is to have an Array and get another array back in return.

Comment: This is more a problem with your definition of `summa`, I believe. Also, note that you are trying to reimplement `itertools.accumulate`; `list(accumulate([1,2,3,4,5], lambda x, y: x + y)) == [1,3,6,10,15]`.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that `reduce(f, [x, y, z])` is equivalent to `f(f(x,y), z)`, not `f(x, f(y, z))`.